# HTML5 form, email not submitting

Tags: php, html

So i've got this assignment at school to make a web page to a company.
I have been using desingmodo's slides template. There is a guide to make a working form but mine isn't sending the email to specified address, but i do get the "success" message after submitting.

send_mail.php

```
<?php
$toEmail = "example@gmail.com"; ***i have the correct email here on my .php***

$mailHeaders = "From: ".$_POST["userName"]." <". $_POST["userEmail"] .">\r\n";

$message_content = "Subject: Contact Form Message\r\n
From: ".$_POST["userName"]." ".$_POST["userEmail"]."\r\n

Message: ".$_POST["content"]."";


if(mail($toEmail, 'Contact Form Message', $message_content, $mailHeaders)) {
    print "<p class='success'>Message Sent. Thank You!</p>";
} else {
    print "<p class='Error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
}
?>
```

HTML form

```
      <form class="wide center" action="send_mail.php" id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
          <label class="uppercase ae-4" for="name37">Your name</label>
          <input class="stroke round ae-5 wide" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required/>
          <span id="userName-info" class="info"></span>
          <label class="uppercase ae-6" for="email37">Email</label>
          <input class="stroke round ae-7 wide" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
          <span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span>
          <label class="uppercase ae-8" for="message37">Message</label>
          <textarea class="stroke round left ae-9 sourceSans" id="message37" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
          <span id="content-info" class="info"></span>
          <input class="button wide pink round uppercase ae-10 button-55 done" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message">
```

im assuming the val_submit.js isnt causing any problems since im getting the "message sent" page.

Any ideas what im missing?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your form with this it will run
Check with name you used in php should be same in form input names

```
  <form class="wide center" action="send_mail.php" id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
              <label class="uppercase ae-4" for="name37">Your name</label>
              <input class="stroke round ae-5 wide" id="name" name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Name" required/>
              <span id="userName-info" class="info"></span>
              <label class="uppercase ae-6" for="email37">Email</label>
              <input class="stroke round ae-7 wide" id="email" type="email" name="userEmail" placeholder="Email" required/>
              <span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span>
              <label class="uppercase ae-8" for="message37">Message</label>
              <textarea class="stroke round left ae-9 sourceSans" id="message37" name="content" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
              <span id="content-info" class="info"></span>
              <input class="button wide pink round uppercase ae-10 button-55 done" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message">
```